# openssl req -new with some default subj values

Tags: openssl

I want to use openssl to create a CSR while providing some of the answers for Country Name, State or Province Name, etc **but** I still want it to prompt for the Common Name (FQDN). So far I have something like:

> openssl req -new -sha256 -key example.com.key -out example.com.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=Ohio/L=Columbus/O=Widgets Inc/OU=Some Unit"

This however does not prompt me for the Common name. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: The FQDN ***is not*** placed in the *Common Name*. That practice was deprecated by both the IETF and CA/B Forums years ago. Instead, hostnames (including IP addresses) go in the *Subject Alternative Name*. Place a friendly name in the *Common Name*, like *Example Web Server* because its displayed for the user in many tools.

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) It provides a lot of background information on X.509 server certificates, how to present names, and where the various rules come from.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it on the command line with `read` and using the result variable in your `openssl` command:

```
read -p "FQDN? " cn; openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout $cn.key -subj "/CN=$cn\/emailAddress=admin@$cn/C=US/ST=Ohio/L=Columbus/O=Widgets Inc/OU=Some Unit" -out $cn.csr
```

If this is something you do often, make it a function and add it to your `.bashrc` file, which allows you to replace the prompt with an argument:

```
function csr { openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout $1.key -subj "/CN=$cn\/emailAddress=admin@$1/C=US/ST=Ohio/L=Columbus/O=Widgets Inc/OU=Some Unit" -out $1.csr }
```

Then envoke it whenever you need to like so:

```
csr example.com
```

The following openssl.conf file does *almost* the same thing:

```
[req]
default_bits=2048
encrypt_key=no
default_md=sha256
distinguished_name=req_subj
[req_subj]
commonName="Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)"
emailAddress="Administrative Email Address"
countryName="Country Name (2 letter code)"
countryName_default=US
stateOrProvinceName="State Name (full name)"
stateOrProvinceName_default=Ohio
localityName="Locality Name (e.g., city)"
localityName_default=Columbus
organizationName="Organization Name (e.g., company)"
organizationName_default=Widgets Inc
organizationalUnitName="Organizational Unit Name (e.g., section)"
organizationalUnitName_default=Some Unit
```

Then either set your `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable to that file

```
export $OPENSSL_CONF=~/.dotfiles/openssl.conf
```

or specify it via switch on the CLI

```
openssl req -new -config openssl.conf -keyout example.key -out example.csr
```

I say *almost* because it still prompts you for those attributes, but they're now the default so you can just hammer the `Return` key to the end after specifying the domain and your email.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do that from only command line values.  I have always used the config file to accomplish this.  For example the entries to set the defaults in your config might look like:

```cfg
policy = policy_anything

# For the 'anything' policy, which defines allowed DN fields
[ policy_anything ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
commonName = supplied
name = optional
emailAddress = optional

####################################################################
# request handling

[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
default_keyfile = private/key.pem
default_md = default
distinguished_name = standard_dn

####################################################################
# DN (Subject) handling

[ standard_dn ]

countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = US
countryName_min = 2
countryName_max = 2

stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = California

localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = Beverily Hills

commonName = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_default = John Smith
commonName_max = 64

emailAddress = Email Address
emailAddress_default = jhn.smith@somewhere.com
emailAddress_max = 64
```

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I wrote this BASH script because I was creating so many CSRs.  If you look closely, you can see how I added the FQDN (host name) as the CN (common name) on the CSR.  This script skips the CSR portion and calls openssl with the "req" and "-x509" options, so it generates a self signed cert instead of a CSR.  But it shows how you can construct a SN with a FQDN on the end as a CN.  It's released under a BSD license, so feel free to use any portion of it.  Specifically, you could probably change the last section to something like this, if you want the CSR:

```
# Now create the CSR
if [ 0 = ${#PASSWORD} ]; then
  openssl req -new -batch -key $CN.key -subj "$SN" -out $CN.crt
else
  openssl req -new -batch -key $CN.key -subj "$SN" -out $CN.crt \
    -passin "pass:$PASSWORD"
fi
```

from: https://gist.github.com/OhMeadhbh/6201808

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) 2003-2013, Meadhbh S. Hamrick. All Rights Reserved.
# Released under a BSD License. See http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause
#
# This script uses openssl to generate a self-signed certificate. Usage is
# like this:
#   gssc <host name> [-p password] [-s subject] [-b bitlength]
# The host name parameter is the subject name of the certificate; i.e. - the
# FQDN of the host you're generating a certificate for. This is also the base
# name for the key, certificate signing request and certificate files. If you
# want the key to be protected by a password, use the -p option to specify
# it. The subject name of the requested cert defaults to:
#   "C=US, ST=California, L=Felton, CN=<host name>"
# You can select a differetn subject name by using the -s option and providing
# a complete openssl style subject name. For example:
#   "/C=IO/ST=Chagos/L=Diego Garcia/CN=foo.bar.mil"
# will specify the expected subject name. Remember to put the slashes
# in front of each clause and to put the Common Name (CN) entry (we don't
# do it for you.) By default, we generate 2048 bit RSA keys. If you want some
# other bit length, use the -b flag.
#
# For example, the following command generates a self signed cert for the
# machine "secure.example.com" with a 1536 bit RSA key and a common name of
# "C=US, ST=Montana, L=Bozeman, CN=secure.example.com":
#   gssc secure.example.com -b 1536 -password "badpassword" \
#       -s "/C=US/ST=Montana/L=Bozeman/CN=secure.example.com"
#
# This example creates a self signed cert for www.example.org with no password
# on the private key and a subject name of "C=US, ST=California, L=Felton,
# CN=www.example.org":
#   fssc www.example.com
#
# Cheers!

# Check to see if we provided a host name
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <host name> [-b bits] [-p password] [-s subject name]"
  exit 1
fi

# Set up defaults
CN=$1
BITS=2048
PASSWORD=""
SN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Felton/CN=$1"

# Now apply the parameters
shift
while getopts "b:p:s:" flag
do
  case $flag in
    b) BITS=$OPTARG;;
    p) PASSWORD=$OPTARG;;
    s) SN=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done

# First off, generate a RSA key
if [ 0 = ${#PASSWORD} ]; then
  openssl genrsa -out $CN.key $BITS
else
  if [ 4 -gt ${#PASSWORD} ]; then
    echo "Your pass phrase must be four or more characters."
    exit 2
  else
    openssl genrsa -out $CN.key -des3 -passout "pass:$PASSWORD" $BITS
  fi
fi

# Now create the certificate
if [ 0 = ${#PASSWORD} ]; then
  openssl req -new -batch -x509 -key $CN.key -subj "$SN" -days 365 -out $CN.crt
else
  openssl req -new -batch -x509 -key $CN.key -subj "$SN" -days 365 -out $CN.crt \
    -passin "pass:$PASSWORD"
fi
```